# Why is this value coming up as ambiguous?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm thoroughly confused as to why I'm getting a ValueError on this code; any help appreciated.

I have a dataframe called global_output with two columns: a column of words and column of corresponding values. I want to perform a median split on the values, and assign the words into two lists--high and low--depending on whether they're above or below the median.

```
       Word         Ranking
0      shuttle      0.9075
1      flying       0.7750
2      flight       0.7250
3      trip         0.6775
4      transport    0.6250
5      escape       0.5850
6      trajectory   0.5250
7      departure    0.5175
8      arrival      0.5175
```

My code for doing this is as follows:

```
split = global_output['Abstraction'].quantile([0.5])

high = []
low = []


for j in range(len(global_output)):
    if global_output['Ranking'][j] > split:
        low_clt.append(global_output['Word'][j])
    else:
        high.append(global_output['Word'][j])
```

However,I keep getting this error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Now, I understand what the error means: it says I'm trying to evaluate a Series with multiple values as if it were a single value. Nevertheless, I just cannot see how

```
global_output['Ranking'][j]
```

is in any way ambiguous when j takes an integer value from the loop. When I input it into the console, it yields a float value every time. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You working with `arrays`, so better is use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `mask` and `loc` for selecting column:

```
#if need column Abstraction, change it
split = global_output['Ranking'].quantile([0.5]).item()
print (split)
0.625

mask = global_output['Ranking'] <= split
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
8     True
Name: Ranking, dtype: bool

high = global_output.loc[~mask, 'Word'].tolist()
low = global_output.loc[mask, 'Word'].tolist()

print (high)
['shuttle', 'flying', 'flight', 'trip']

print (low)
['transport', 'escape', 'trajectory', 'departure', 'arrival']
```

---

Your solution works also, only need convert one item `Series` to `scalar` by `item()` and it seems `>` has to be `<`:

```
split = global_output['Ranking'].quantile([0.5])
print (split)
0.5    0.625
Name: Ranking, dtype: float64

split = global_output['Ranking'].quantile([0.5]).item()
print (split)
0.625
```

And you get `error` because you compare one item `Series`.

Comment: Ah, I see! The ambiguity was coming from global_output['Ranking'].quantile([0.5]). This resolves the problem very neatly. Thanks for the really helpful suggestions about masking, too!

Comment: Exactly. you are right - need compare both scalars.